# Edit the question or ask a new one?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a [question about memory usage](https://superuser.com/questions/896008/memory-not-unloading?noredirect=1#comment1217095_896008) that was a little ill-informed on my part, and it turns out the issue is being caused by something else entirely. Before I add any more information I'm inclined to just forget this one and ask a new one.

Should I edit my current one or ask a new one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question already has a couple of answers, and is closed as "too broad". If you later understood that the issue is different enough to invalidate the current answers, I'd post a new question. Additionally, I'd mention the current question in the new one - "I recently asked about X and was helped by the answers I've got, but recently understood the problem is Y, so I'm posting a new question."

Comment: How does this co-exist with the fact that questions should be as "standalone" as possible (and not linked as a follow-up to another question)?